# Need help with designing a 24V and 12V regulator with the LT1074

Tags: circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply

I need help with calculating all the needed capacitor, resistor and inductor values for two switching regulators since i'm kind of confused with the datasheet. The regulators are 12V and 24V and both use an LT1074.
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1074fds.pdf

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far? Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: I haven't tried much yet. I'm currently figuring out how to use LTSpice.

Comment: There are excellent guides. See if there is a built-in test bench for LT1074.

Comment: Thanks; i'll try that. If i still have issues, i'll come back

Comment: I can't seem to find any terms for any values such as the inductor value or how to calculate anything on the Vc pin. I also didn't find any test bench for the LT1074. I may not have searched in the right places though.

Comment: Page 33: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an44fa.pdf